# maven wrapper permission denied

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-wraper

Estoy tomando un curso de springboot y ahora estoy en la parte de compilar la app y hacer despliegues pero el comando `./mvnw.cmd package`
no me funciona y me da este mensaje bash: `./mvnw.cmd: Permission denied`, no tengo actualmente maven instalado en el equipo solo estoy unsando el embebido que incluyen los proyectos de springboot, pense que era un tema de super usuario pero defintivamente no es.

**Información extra:** estoy usando **Java 16** en ubuntu 20.04 la app es solo un empoint que devuelve lo que recibe en un path variable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dice que no tienes permisos en tu maven wrapper, intenta cambiarle los permisos de lectura y ejecución

Comment: El archivo `mvnw.cmd` es para ejecutar en windows, debes de utilizar el que no tiene extensión que es para Bash por ejemplo `./mvnw clean install`, además debes de revisar si tienes los permisos de ejecución.